# @WithStateMachine with @EnableStateMachineFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I was trying to use @WithStateMachine with @StateMachineConfigEnums, and I can't see my functions getting called.

My code is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class StateMachineConfigEnums extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {

}
@WithStateMachine
public class OrderTransitionBean {
    @OnTransition(target = "RECEIVED")
    void toState1() {
        System.out.println("Manish toState1");
    }
```

There might be a simple answer that it is not supported and @WithStateMachine only work with @EnableStateMachine. Or probably I am missing something.

Though other things are working like below or action defined with transitions:

```
public class OrderStateMachineListener extends StateMachineListenerAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(State<String, String> from, State<String, String> to) {
        System.out.println("Order state changed to " + to.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right about this, it's not supported as annotation support only works with registered beans and in this case bean is a state machine factory, not machine itself. As you're first one to request this, I created in issue for it [gh-224](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/224).

Comment: Thanks for confirming, at least I don't need to put any effort.

Comment: I having the same issue with 1.2.8.RELEASE.

Comment: While debugging find solution, need to set machine name for WithStateMachine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else trying to figure out how to make this work, this is now possible. You need to give a name to your state machine.

You need to provide a name for the `@WithStateMachine` annotation. Ex:

`@WithStateMachine(name = StateMachineNameConstants.STATE_MACHINE_NAME)`

You must also specify the same name when using the factory to create the state machine:

`stateMachine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine(StateMachineNameConstants.STATE_MACHINE_NAME);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Enums instead of strings, then create an annotation called @StateonTransition ( check the official spring state machine site for this) instead of @OnTransition.

Comment: I am using String as we have to persist the state and and PersistStateMachineHandler.PersistStateChangeListener doesn't support enum